# CKEDITOR Error code: editor-destroy-iframe in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am using `ng2-ckeditor` in my `Angular2` project. It is working fine but when I go on another component, It shows warning message `[CKEDITOR] Error code: editor-destroy-iframe`.
I google for solution and found below solution:

```
for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);
    }
```

But from where to get `CKEDITOR`. In `ng2-ckeditor` package, I can see only 2 library `CKEditorModule, CKEditorComponent`.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I have a similar issue with editor-destroy-iframe, where in your code did you put that snippet to destroy the editor? I tried to put in ngOnDestroy  but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the typescript definition file for CKEditor in package.json under devDependencies ("@types/ckeditor": "^0.0.34"):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~2.4.0",
    "@types/ckeditor": "^0.0.34"
}
```

Then run npm update to download the types.
An alternate solution is to declare CKEditor in your file:

```
declare const CKEDITOR: any;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the reported problem?